# Can I remove Sharepoint subscriptions from a disabled user?

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, exchange-server

The user was disabled in AD. Deleted his mailbox from Exchange (2013).

But i have a problem. The user apparently had previously subscribed to changes are different files in Sharepoint (2013) and letter of changes still trying to send on an already disabled mailbox.

How can I fix this problem? Is it possible to unsubscribe users in Sharepoint in bulk? 
Should block the subscriptions when the user account is disabled?

Thanks in advance!